# Why is my table view shadow scrolling with my table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I added shadow to my table view but unfortunately when I scroll through the table view the shadow also moves with the table. The code for adding shadow is as follows:

```
func addShadow(to myView: UIView){
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: uiView.frame.width, height: uiView.frame.height * 1.1))
        uiView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        uiView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.2, height: 0)
        uiView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        uiView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        uiView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        uiView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }
```

[image]

Can you please explain to me why is this happening and how to make the shadow stick to its designated location?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because you've add a shadow to your `UITableView` which is fixed, and it is not your `UITableView` which is scrolling. You scroll your cells !

Comment: How did you call `addShadow` method?

Comment: @AhmadF I call the addShadow method like so: addShadow(to: tableViewController.view). I am not adding the shadow to the table view itself but to the view of the table view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding shadow on tableView, it will scroll along with tableview data. To prevent that you have to add UIView first. Add tableview on that view. Add shadow for the UIView you have taken. It will stick to designated location.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in **Swift 3** with an `UIView` and a `CAGradientLayer` inside.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      addShadow(myView: myTab)
 }

func addShadow(myView: UIView){        
    let shadowView = UIView()
    shadowView.center = CGPoint(x: myView.frame.minX,y:myView.frame.minY - 15)
    shadowView.frame.size = CGSize(width: myView.frame.width, height: 15)
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame.size = shadowView.frame.size
    let stopColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    let startColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor
    gradient.colors = [stopColor,startColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0,1.0]
    shadowView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    view.addSubview(shadowView)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Rob, thank you for your answer. But what I noticed in your code is that the shadow is added to the parent view of the table view. The table view has a pan gesture recognizer attached to it to slide it down and hide it from view. I'd image with your code the shadowView will stay in place while the table view slides to the bottom. I need the shadow to slide with the table view **and** not scroll out of place when scrolling the information in the table view. For a reference of what I am looking for you can take look at the official Apple's Map app.